# Mixed Poisson Distriubtion

Tags: probability, statistics

Question:
The number of accidents follows a Poisson distribution with mean 12. Each accident generates 1, 2 or 3 claimants with probabilities 1/6,1/3,1/2, respectively.
Calculate the probability that there are at most 3 claimants.

Attempt:
$$
E(N) = 12[\frac{1}{6}+2*\frac{1}{3}+3*\frac{1}{2}] = 12*\frac{7}{3}=28
$$

Step 2:
$$
P(N≤3) = \sum_{x=0}^3\frac{28^xe^{-28}}{x!} = 2.8*10^{-9}
$$

That's the answer I got, but the number seems to be too small in value. Did I do anything wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\frac16+\frac13+\frac12=1$ showing that each accident generates at least $1$ and at most $3$ claimants.

Let $K$ and $N$ denote the number of accidents and claimants respectively.

$$P\left(N\leq3\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P\left(N\leq3\mid K=k\right)P\left(K=k\right)$$

This with $P\left(K=k\right)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}$
where $\lambda=12$, and with:

$P\left(N\leq3\mid K=0\right)=1$

$P\left(N\leq3\mid K=1\right)=1$

$P\left(N\leq3\mid K=2\right)=\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{6}$

$P\left(N\leq3\mid K=3\right)=\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{6}$

$P\left(N\leq3\mid K=k\right)=0$ if $k\geq4$

---

**edit**:

This results in $$P(N\leq3)=e^{-12}\left[1.1+1.12+\frac{5}{36}\frac{12^{2}}{2}+\frac{1}{6^{3}}\frac{12^{3}}{6}\right]=\frac{73}{3}e^{-12}$$

Comment: Awesome!Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've covered [probability generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function) in your coursework, but they will be useful here:

Let $g(z)$ be the PGF of the number of claims per accident, then:

$$g(z)=1/6z+1/3z^2+1/2z^3$$

Lets call the PGF of the poisson distribution $h(z)$:

$$h(z)=e^{\lambda(z-1)}$$

There is a useful property of random [sums of positive discrete random variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function#Functions_of_independent_random_variables) (both X and N are random and discrete valued):

$$S_N:=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i \implies PGF(S_N)=PGF_N(PGF_X)$$

So, in your case, the total number of claims, $C$ is a random sum of $N\sim Poisson(12)$ accidents, each having a random number of claims:

$$C_N=\sum_{i=1}^N C_i \implies PGF(C_N)=h(g(z))=e^{2z+4z^2+6z^3-12}$$

Expanding this as a product of three power series (one per exponential term), we get:

$$e^{-12}\left(\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{(2z)^i}{i!} \right)\left(\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{(4z)^{2i}}{i!} \right)\left(\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{(6z)^{3i}}{i!} \right)$$

We want the coefficients for the terms corresponding to $z,z^2,z^3$:

$$e^{-12}\left[2z+\left(\frac{4}{2!}+\frac{16}{1!}\right)z^2+ \left(\frac{216}{1!}+\frac{16}{1!}\frac{2}{1!}+\frac{8}{3!}\right)z^3\right]=e^{-12}\left[2z+18z^2+ 249.33z^3\right]$$

Therefore:

$$P(C_N\leq 3)=e^{-12}\left[2+18+ 249.33\right]\approx .00165$$

Comment: How do you know when it's the best time to use PGF to answer questions?

Comment: The idea is okay, but unfortunately there are mistakes in it: the
second summand is $\frac{\left(4z^{2}\right)^{i}}{i!}=\frac{4^{i}z^{2i}}{i!}$
and the third is: $\frac{\left(6z^{3}\right)^{i}}{i!}=\frac{6^{i}z^{3i}}{i!}$.
This leads to the expansion $e^{-12}\left[1+2z+6z^{2}+15\frac{1}{3}z^{3}+\cdots\right]$
and $P\left(C_{N}\leq3\right)=e^{-12}\left[1+2+6+15\frac{1}{3}\right]$ matching my answer.
The constant term - corresponding with $P\left(C_{N}=0\right)$ - is
abusively left out.

Comment: I meant to say "mistakenly" instead of "abusively". Sorry for my English ;)